# Hibernate Mapping annotations

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am very new to hibernate...I want to use hibernate mapping annotations but not sure how to use those..I have read some articles but still confused...These are my model classes..

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class User {
    public User() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Date date;
    private char gender;
    private char isMarried;
    private String password;
    private char status;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    Contact contact;

    public User(int id, String name, Date date, char gender, char isMarried,
            String password, char status) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.isMarried = isMarried;
        this.password = password;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public char getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public char getIsMarried() {
        return isMarried;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public char getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public boolean validate(String password) {
        if (this.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    public void changePassword(String newPassword)
    {
        if(this.validate(getPassword()))
        {
            System.out.println(password);
            this.password=newPassword;
            System.out.println(password);
        }

    }
}


@Entity
public class Customer extends User{

    public Customer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    private String occupation;

    public Customer(int id, String name, Date date, char gender,
            char isMarried, String password, char status) {
        super(id, name, date, gender, isMarried, password, status);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getOccupation() {
        return occupation;
    }


}


@Entity

public class Contact {

    @Id
    int id;
    String email;
    String mobile;
    String city;
    String pin;
    String address;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }
    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getPin() {
        return pin;
    }
    public void setPin(String pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}


ublic class Account {

    private long accId;
    private double sum;
    public long getAccId() {
        return accId;
    }
    public void setAccId(long accId) {
        this.accId = accId;
    }
    public double getSum() {
        return sum;
    }
    public void setSum(double sum) {
        this.sum = sum;
    }

}

public class Payee {

    int id;
    long accId;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public long getAccId() {
        return accId;
    }
    public void setAccId(long accId) {
        this.accId = accId;
    }

}
```

Database queries should be like these.....

```sql
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `accId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `sum` float NOT NULL,
  `owner_id` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`accId`),
  KEY `FK1D0C220DBB52EA6F` (`owner_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK1D0C220DBB52EA6F` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `contact` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `address` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `pin` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dob` datetime default NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `married` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `contact_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `occupation` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `FK285FEB4AFD7C1027fbe3fe` (`contact_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK285FEB4AFD7C1027fbe3fe` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `contact` (`id`)
);



CREATE TABLE `payee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `accId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `payer_id` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `FK4954328AA304E8D` (`payer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK4954328AA304E8D` FOREIGN KEY (`payer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`)
);
```

please anyone help....what should be the annotations in my model classes.....

Comment: PrimaryKeyJoinColumn is when you want the primary key to also be a foreign key. That's not what you want. You want a separate join column named contact_id: `@JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")`. Instead of letting us guess what the problem is, why don't you tell us? What happens when you test that code. Any exception? What's the message?

Comment: forget about the database queries i wrote..just consider my model clasees.N wan one to many relationships with customer and payee...and with customer and account...what are the annotations i should use??thank you!  @JBNizet

Comment: you could reverse engineer from the existing database schema http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/